# Nginx dynamic sub folder as fastcgi_param

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I have a PHP site being served by Nginx.  I want to be able to access it via different sub folders. Basically, a user can sign up and when they do they choose set a "url".  Based on that, they will access the site like this:

```
example.com/{url}
```

I'd also be ok with something like:

```
example.com/s/{url}
```

if that would help with detecting it.

I want Nginx to grab that URL and pass it to PHP using fastcgi_param. Also, I want PHP to behave as if the site was accessed via just `example.com`. So for example, `example.com/s/{url}/about` would be the same as `example.com/about`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to strip the first part of the site URL path component from the URL passed to PHP. This is how you can do it:

```
location ~ ^(?<userurl>[^/]+)(<dest>/.+)$ {
    rewrite ^ $dest break;
}
```

So, this will change URLs like this:

`http://example.com/about/something` becomes `http://example.com/something`.

`http://example.com/about` becomes `http://example.com/`

The regex also captures the part after first `/` to the variable `$userurl`, which you can use in your `fastcgi_param` to pass the part of the URL to the PHP script.

However, instead of splitting the work between nginx and your PHP script, I recommend implementing the front-controller pattern in your PHP script. That means, it will parse the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and process the request according to the rules you implement in PHP.

Then, in nginx you just add:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
```

in the virtual host section for processing the requests.